# If $A_q$ is open for all $q \in \mathbb Q$ prove $A_r$ is open for all $r \in \mathbb R$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, alternative-proof

The problem is as follows. Let $X$ be a metric space and $f: X \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that $A_q = \{x \in X: f(x) < q\}$ is open for all $q \in \mathbb Q$. Prove $A_r = \{x \in X: f(x) < r\}$ is open for all $r \in \mathbb R$.

My idea is to define $\{q_n\}$ to be a sequence of rational numbers such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n \to r$$
Now  $$A_r = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z_+}A_{q_n}$$
Does this construction work? If this is correct, I would be glad to see an alternative proof that doesn't rely on convergent sequences.

Comment: doesn't work. you need $q_n \uparrow r$. If you don't want sequences, you can just do $\cup_{q < r} A_q$, which is basically the same thing

Comment: @mathworker21 What does the first notation mean?

Comment: $q_n$ increases to $r$. i just wanted to convey that you want/need each $q_n < r$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Indeed that was what I tried to convey with the limit. However, I realize that it doesn't work. Regarding your alternative proof, this is exactly the approach I would like to avoid. Do you have any alternative ideas besides $\bigcup_{q<r}A_q$?

Comment: no. you know nothing about $f$, so the only thing you can really use about $A_r$ is that it is the union of some $A_q$'s. so yea, nothing else you can use. idk why u wanna avoid the union

Comment: @mathworker21 Just for the fun of it

Comment: don't think you'll be able to have that fun